# Is it possible to download apps from another country?

Tags: xbox-360

I live in Australia, and I was wondering if there was anyway to access applications from the U.S such as Hulu?

Comment: It's all IP based. You would need to set up a proxy. There are proxy hosting sites, and reasonably intricate ways to do this without one of those services. There was another question that was kind of like this. Where someone had wanted to keep playing a Japanese based game out of that region. I am simply relaying the more pertinent solutions that were discussed on that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Region-Free account. In order to complete this task:

1. Go to the Hotmail account on a PC. Press the “Get account” button to go to a new window. Click on the ‘Get it” button beneath the “Windows Live Hotmail” text.
2. Type in any name you choose in the “Screen name” column on the new window that appears. Type in a password in the “Password” column below “Screen Name.” Type in the password again in the “Retype Password” column. Fill in the other columns as dictated by the text.
3. Select the country (i.e., region) of the game that you are not allowed to play from the “Country/Region” drop-down menu. Select a city for that country from the “City” drop-down menu below “Country/Region.” Enter the postcode for the city in the “Postcode” column below “City.”
4. Enter the special code that is at the bottom of the webpage into the column designated for it. Press the “Finish” button to complete making your profile.
5. Turn on the Xbox 360. Navigate to the “Network” setting from the Home menu. Select “Join Xbox Live” from the list of choices presented. Wait for the Xbox Live window to appear on the screen. Click on the ‘Continue” button. Enter a game name using the onscreen keyboard that appears. Click “Done.” Click “Yes” on the screen that appears.
6. Enter the e-mail address used for the profile you made using the onscreen keyboard in the window that appears. Click “Done.”
7. Enter the password you had used for the profile you made in the next screen using the onscreen keyboard. Click “Done.”
8. Wait for the Home screen to appear. Download or view whatever you want now that you are not locked to your own region. Quit Xbox Live when you are done.
9. Return to the Hotmail signup web page and create a new profile when you want to access a different region on your Xbox 360.

Comment: While it's possible to have them on the dashboard, it doesn't mean you can *use* them. I have a US-based Live account but I live in the EU. I can open Netflix, but because I don't live in the right region (it bases this off IP, I believe), it still won't let me actually use it.

Comment: @FAE I'm UK-based and easily able to access various applications with Region Free.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it's restricted...

Comment: @EfcSeany Is there a particular reason you rolled back the formatting edit?

Comment: @DoozerBlake There was no option for me to accept the changes.

Comment: @EfcSeany likely because the changes were made by a user with full edit privileges. In the future, if you don't want to rollback an edit, and there isn't an option to approve, don't do anything.